# Tailwind css does not reduce file size after purge

Tags: css, tailwind-css

i have a basic html file (index.html), my project structure is like below :

- index.html
- tailwind.config.js
- postcss.js
- tailwind.css
- dist.css

and here contents for each files

```
module.exports = {
purge: {
    enabled:true,
    content:['./*.html', './**/*.html'],
    layers: ['components']
},
theme: {
    extend: {
        fontSize:{
            'small' : '.6rem',
            // Or with a default line-height as well
            '3xl': ['2.5rem', {
                lineHeight: '50px',
            }],
            '6xl': ['3.70rem', {
                lineHeight: '60px',
            }],
        },
        colors:{
            transparent: 'transparent',
            current: 'currentColor',
            orange:{
                DEFAULT: '#F47521'
            }
        },
        screens: {
            'sm': '640px',
            'md': '760px',
            'custom' : '980px',
            'lg': '1024px',
            'xl': '1280px',
            '2xl': '1536px',
            '3xl': '1600px',
            'xxl' : '1700px'
        }
    }
},
variants: {
    textColor: ['responsive', 'hover', 'focus', 'visited'],
},
plugins: [
    ({addUtilities}) => {
        const utils = {
            '.translate-x-half': {
                transform: 'translateX(50%)',
            },
        };
        addUtilities(utils, ['responsive'])
    }
]
};
```

**the postcss file**

```
module.exports = {
    plugins: {
        tailwindcss: {},
        autoprefixer: {},
    }
}
```

and my package.json

```
{
  "name": "myproject",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "my theme",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "build": "NODE_ENV=production npx tailwindcss-cli@latest build tailwind.css -o dist.css",
    "build:css": "postcss tailwind.css -o dist.css"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
  "autoprefixer": "^10.2.5",
  "postcss": "^8.2.8",
  "tailwindcss": "^2.0.4"
  },
   "dependencies": {
      "cssnano": "^4.1.10",
      "postcss-cli": "^8.3.1"
   }
}
```

when building with : npm run build, tailwind build the project but the dist.css size remains 5,7MB

What i'm doing wrong here?

thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have purge configured to apply to the 'components' layer.

Tailwind has three layers: 'base', 'components', and 'utilities'. Components is the smallest of the three so its impact on the resulting filesize will be fairly minimal. You're hitting 5.7MB because by far the largest layer, 'utilities', is being ignored.

Update your purge configuration to apply to utilities too. Unless there's a good reason to be selective with layers, you probably want to drop any specificity and allow it to apply to all layers.

Furthermore, if you leave out `enabled`, it will be handled automatically based on your `NODE_ENV` setting.

https://tailwindcss.com/docs/optimizing-for-production#purging-specific-layers

Comment: hey, you're right about "utilities", thanks a lot

Comment: Hi Nathan. I'm a newbie at Tailwind and am reading around on Tailwind's potential impact on performance. I came across [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67600655/next-js-with-tailwind-refreshes-slow). Would I still experience the sluggish refresh rate they are referring to if I purge correctly?

Comment: @TommyWolheart I know CSS inside out but wherever possible nowadays I'd use Tailwind. With purging setup correctly your CSS file output will be tiny.

Comment: That’s great, thanks! I’ll go ahead and give it a try it in my project then and see how it goes.