# Next.js with Tailwind Refreshes Slow

Tags: performance, next.js, refresh, reload, tailwind-css

I experienced an extremely sluggish refresh time after adding Tailwind to my small Next project. I initially thought it was my device.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved it by removing the

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

from my global.css file. The disadvantage to this is that you will not be able to apply tailwind classes inline but you can still write your tailwind in your css files and use @apply.

Comment: I am facing a similar issue, but the project is at such a stage I cannot move the inline classes to CSS. It's a lot of refactoring and maybe defeats some purpose of tailwind being inline-class utility. Hope there's a better solution out there.

Comment: Can you clarify regarding "apply tailwind classes inline"? Do you mean that classes cannot be used in components directly?

Comment: Yes. You won't be able to use each Tailwind utility classes in your components. You'll have to create (a) separate CSS file(s) for them.

Answer (score 4):

I solved this by using [Tailwind's just-in-time mode](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/just-in-time-mode).

```
// tailwind.config.js

module.exports = {
 mode: 'jit',
 ...
}
```

This feature is currently in preview, which means it's subject to change, but it worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by removing `@tailwind` directives from `global.css` file like  @GeniusHawlah.

then [Tailwind CLI](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/installation):

```
npx tailwindcss -i ./src/input.css -o ./dist/output.css --watch
```

and i imported `output.css` to my global.css.
when i edit `*.jsx` files, `tailwindcss` update `output.css`.